# Run/Execute CasperJS script by clicking a button on webpage

Tags: php, javascript, api, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a casperJS script which returns a JSON when run on commandline. I want to have an arrangement such that 
1) I create a webpage 
2) On clicking a button on the webpage the casperJS scripts gets executed at the server side and post/return the result back to the webpage.

How can i do the same.

EDIT: I am invoking an AJAX process written in php on clicking the buttom. The php script contains 
`echo exec('casperjs sample.js');` 
It returned nothing but on checking the webserver error log I got the error 
`'casperjs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

PS: It running absolutely fine via commandline.

EDIT2 
I changed the php script to: 
`echo exec('C:\casperjs\batchbin\casperjs .\sample.js');` 
The error got modified to : 
`'phantonjs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CasperJS passing data back to PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852987/casperjs-passing-data-back-to-php)

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution from my post on google group

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/casperjs/7Lps6TiX-78

It worked by moving CasperJS & PhantomJS executable file in the directory server (/html)